# Setting Default HTTP Header "Cache-Control" not working with S3 Browser

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to use the **S3 Browser** Windows client (http://s3browser.com/) to have the "Cache-Control" header default to "max-age=0".

It is not working.  I know this because once I upload a file (from my Web server to AWS S3), the header is not there.

Here's what my Default HTTP Header settings look like:

[image]

**Does anyone know why this header is not being set for newly-uploaded files?**

I am running S3 Browser version 3-7-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstood what the Default HTTP Header does.  I thought that if I set a default header, the header would be set even if I uploaded files from my web server to S3.  This is not true; Default HTTP Headers only affect files uploaded from the S3 Browser program.